# riskieren + gesundheit : Can use this verb?

Tags: english-to-german

Does anyone say in Germany like this:

My friend wrote he has positiv test. I have met him...I can come ...
*** Bei mir ist alles gut, aber für ihre Sicherheit, weil sie kurz OP hatten,  möchte ich ihre Gesundheit nicht riskieren***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short:** Yes, *riskieren* can be used this way (I have corrected the original text a little):

> Bei mir ist alles gut, aber zu Ihrer Sicherheit, weil Sie vor kurzem eine OP hatten, möchte ich Ihre *Gesundheit* nicht *riskieren*.

**In detail:** Basically, *etwas riskieren* can be used in two ways, which may seem contradictory. On the one hand, *etwas* may refer to something of value that you **lose** when you fail. For example:

> Er riskierte *seine Arbeitsstelle*/ *sein Leben*/ *seine Gesundheit* …
>
> <sub>(He was risking *his job*/ *his life*/ *his health* …)</sub>

On the other hand, *etwas* may refer to something that you do not want, but that you **get** when you fail, such as a penalty. For example:

> Er riskierte *eine Tracht Prügel*/ *ein Hausverbot*/ *eine Geldstrafe* …
>
> <sub>(He was risking *a spanking*/ *a ban from the building*/ *a fine* …)</sub>

Comment: thank you for your explanation. Frohe Ostern!

Comment: @FrHart64, danke gleichfalls. :-)

Comment: All reasonable, but a german in every day conversation would say "gefährden", not riskieren.